# Fast enough HTML5 Google Maps API in a non-native app (Sencha and Phonegap solutions)

Tags: html, cordova, google-maps-api-3, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to use Phonegap and Sencha to create some apps.

I do know native development results in a faster application, but I'd like to give a try to the "so famous" HTML5 dark(?) side.

I've been trying a simple and minimal installation of Phonegap and Sencha kits and then put a jQueryMobile, and then a Google Maps API typical example... SLOW even on my Galaxy S2... Needless to say slow too on an iPhone 3.

So I decided to remove jQueryMobile and compile the smallest possible Sencha and Phonegap boilerplates with a simple HTML5 web page calling the Google Maps API. And... SLOW !

(Obviously) Nothing to do with the native solutions... or not ?

Does anybody know a fast enough solution to put a Google Maps without developing native apps? (or if I need to develop an app with a map I have to go to native)

**Note:** I tried the latest versions of everything... Google Maps v3 API, Sencha Touch 2, Phonegap 1.7.1.

Tested codes:

- http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?156501-Maps-with-sencha-touch
- http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt4part1
- APP: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mds.gmapdemo&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEwMiwiY29tLm1kcy5nbWFwZGVtbyJd
- http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-mobile.html

All these examples are remarkably slow comparing to native solution in a Galaxy S2 ... and very very very slow, in other "typical" Android.

Comment: The Google Maps API is the Google Maps API regardless if what it's running on. How are you calling it? What are you trying to do? What does your code look like? Hard to answer your question when you give us so little to go on.

Comment: I'll answer you with a question ... do you know any app (Play or AppStore) running a Google Maps in a non-native environment and running (almost at least) as fast as in a native solution ? :P

Comment: There you have all the examples ...

Answer (score 1):

you could try nokia maps html5:
http://api.maps.nokia.com/en/mobile/
(mh5 framework)

It has a very fast mapping implementation!